# Clickable 'fill' in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
url <- c( "http://url1" , "http://ur2")
word <- c( "word1" , "word2")
n <- c( 1 , 1)
res <- as_tibble(data.frame("url"=url , "word"=word stringsAsFactors = F))
res
```

renders tibble :

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
    url     word     n score
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    t1 abnormal     1     1
2    t2     good     1     2
```

I then render a `geom_col` using :

```
ggplot(data=res) + geom_col(show.legend = TRUE, mapping=aes(x=url , y=score, fill=url))
```

which renders :

[image]

Can the url bars and/or fill options to right of chart be clickable ? So that by clicking the bar and/or url 'box' options to right opens the associated url, in this case `"http://url1"` or `"http://ur2"` ?

Comment: maybe check "embed hyperlink ggplot" results, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071210/how-to-furnish-a-ggplot2-figure-with-a-hyperlink